# How to use the @ character in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to do the following - for each *.sql file in the current directory run

```
sqlplus username/password@connect_identifier_specified_in_argument @file_name
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
$scripts = dir *.sql
foreach($script in $scripts) {
    Write-Host sqlplus username/password"@"$args "@"$script.Name
}
```

(I know Write-Host outputs it to the screen; I'm just trying to debug for now.)

However, there is something funky with how PowerShell treats the `@` character and when I run this I always get something like:

```
PS C:\code\scripts> C:\utils\run_sql_scripts_on.ps1 identifier
sqlplus username/password@identifier @ ALERTS.sql
```

See that space after the "@"? What gives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escape the `@` with a backtick (`).

```
Write-Host sqlplus username/password`@$args `@$script.Name
```

Comment: What do the ` and @ symbols actually do?

Comment: The backtick is the escape character in PowerShell. The @ can be used in PS to create empty arrays, for example $a = @(). In this case, I don't think the @ was the problem, but rather the double-quotes. Replace the @'s with a letter and you'll still see the extra space. I think Write-Host automatically puts a space after a double-quoted string.

Comment: The problem is that PowerShell saw "@" and $script.home as two separate arguments because the second is an expression and Write-Host joins all arguments with a space.

Answer (score 2):

[PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) has a handy little utility (echoargs) for debugging this sort of problem:

```
5>echoargs username/password"@"$args "@"$script.Name
Arg 0 is <username/password@>
Arg 1 is <@>
Arg 2 is <test.txt>
```

Try escaping with a backtick:

```
6>echoargs "username/password`@$args" "`@$($script.Name)"
Arg 0 is <username/password@>
Arg 1 is <@test.txt>
```