# sqlplus - No characters are allowed after a here-string header but before the end of the line

Tags: powershell, sqlplus

I'm trying to use sqlplus to do an Oracle query for the first time in a PowerShell script.  I get this error message:

```
At line:1 char:73
+ ... user/pw@RRRPRD.company.net:1521/RRRPRDC @"C:\Users\ ...
+                                                                 ~
No characters are allowed after a here-string header but before the end of the line.
```

It seems to be pointing to the C: after @".  Any ideas? I seem to be doing what is at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67353995/executing-sql-file-with-sqlplus-in-windows-10-powershell) example. I get the same error when I try to do [echoargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812882/how-to-use-the-character-in-powershell) of the connection info.

This is my powershell code I am testing at the command line since it hangs forever running the program:

```
sqlplus user/pw@RRRPRD.company.net:1521/RRRPRDC @"C:\Users\me\Documents\2021\temp endToEnd\short.sql"
```

This is using powershell 5.1.  Any ideas?  I see [here string header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50482528/no-characters-are-allowed-after-a-here-string-header-but-before-the-end-of-the-l), but since I am following the example that was accepted in the link for sqlplus above, it's unclear to me what's wrong with it.

Comment: You're missing the closing of the here string. Also, why not just use a regular string? You also seem to be missing some spaces in between each parameter

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - do you have an example? I'm unclear on what you're saying.

Comment: A *here-string* begins with `@"` and ends with `"@`. It looks like a regular string would do as well

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - I tried adding a @ after the end doublequote and it had the same error message, and pointing to the "C: still

Comment: I'm not familiar with calling on sqlplus, but as mentioned earlier, there seems to be a space missing separating the parameters. You also don't need a here string from the looks of it. A simple: `"my string here"` would do; i.e. a regular string with double, or single quotes.

Comment: Looks like you mean to use a regular string in a command line. So just remove the `@` in front of the quote where the string starts. Now, PowerShell is interpreting it as the start of a Here-string which needs to end with `"@` **at the beginning of a new line.**

Comment: I tried sqlplus user/pw@RRRPRD.company.net:1521/RRRPRDC "C:\Users\me\Documents\2021\temp endToEnd\short.sql" and it shows me syntax for sqlplus.  Not sure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
@"C:\Users\me\Documents\2021\temp endToEnd\short.sql"
```

with any of the following:

- `` `@"C:\Users\me\Documents\2021\temp endToEnd\short.sql" ``
- `"@C:\Users\me\Documents\2021\temp endToEnd\short.sql"`
- `'@C:\Users\me\Documents\2021\temp endToEnd\short.sql'`

<sup>Note: Using a [verbatim (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) is arguably the best choice here, given that the path contains no *variable references*; if it did, a [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) would be equired.</sup>

All variations end up passing the following string verbatim to `sqlplus`, which I presume is your intent:

`@C:\Users\me\Documents\2021\temp endToEnd\short.sql`

---

Presumably, you're trying to pass `@` as a *verbatim* part of an argument to `sqlplus` - a common convention among CLIs is to use `@<file-path>` to request that argument data be taken *from a file* rather than using the argument value itself.

However, unlike in other shells, **`@` is a *metacharacter* in PowerShell** that serves a variety of purposes.

Thus, a `@` that should be a *verbatim* character at the start of an argument must **either be *escaped* (with `` ` ``) or *part of a quoted string***, as shown above. See the conceptual [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) help topic.

If an *unescaped* argument-initial `@` is followed by `"` or `'`, PowerShell thinks you're trying to create a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings), which has special, multi-line syntax requirements; the error message indicates that they're not met.